# Exterior Derivative on Curved Manifold (SpaceTime)

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation

Considering the 2-Form Gauge Potential $B_{\mu \nu}$, we can write $dB=H$.

In a flat manifold we have that $H_{\mu \nu \rho}=\partial_{\mu}B_{\nu \rho}+\partial_{\rho}B_{\mu \nu}+\partial_{\nu}B_{\rho \mu}$, does this still applies on a curved manifold (spacetime)? Or we have to substitute the normal derivatives with the covariant derivatives?
($H_{\mu \nu \rho}=\nabla_{\mu}B_{\nu \rho}+\nabla_{\rho}B_{\mu \nu}+\nabla_{\nu}B_{\rho \mu}$).

I know that if the potential is a 1-form ($A_\mu$) the result is the same, but I want to know what is the correct definition for a generic $p$-form potential.

Answer (score 6):

The [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) $\mathrm{d}$ needs no [connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(mathematics)) $\nabla$. The two types of derivatives on $p$-forms are the same if the connection $\nabla$ is torsionfree.

Comment: Oh Thanks! And what about if the connection $\nabla$ is not TorsionFree?

The correct definition should be with the partial derivative $\partial$ then?

Comment: Yes, if you mean the exterior derivative $\mathrm{d}$.

Comment: Ok, perfect. And there exist some kind of "exterior covariant derivative" $\tilde{d}$ constructed with the connection $\nabla$? Or this has no use?

Comment: Yes, it's mathematically well-defined. Whether it is relevant in physics is another matter.